# На что ругается npm ("attempt to concatenate local 'package) nil value")

Tags: windows, npm, grunt, node.js

установил grunt в папку с проектом, в командной строке пишет вот это:

> ...23\Desktop\cmder/vendor/clink-completions/npm_prompt.lua:11:
>   attempt to concatenate local 'package) nil value F:\local
>   serv\home\bonsanko.loc {git}{hg}

В другой папке все нормально,

> F:\local serv\home\prot.loc (master) (prot.loc@1.0.0)

Подскажите что это и как бороться?

Comment: Возможно, версии grunt и node.js в Вашем проекте не подходят друг другу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема возникает потому что у вас в файле package.json отсутствуют атрибуты `name` и `version`.

---

Дабы не получать эту ошибку в дальнейшем нужно сделать следующее:

1. Откройте файл `npm_prompt.lua`
2. Найдите в нем следующие строки:

   `local package_name = string.match(package_info, '"name"%s*:%s*"(%g-)"')
   local package_version = string.match(package_info, '"version"%s*:%s*"(.-)"')`
3. Замените их следующим кодом:

`local package_name = string.match(package_info, '"name"%s*:%s*"(%g-)"')
if package_name == nil then
    package_name = '<invalid_name>'
end

local package_version = string.match(package_info, '"version"%s*:%s*"(.-)"')
if package_version == nil then
    package_version = '<invalid_version>'
end`

Или просто обновите `Cmder` до версии `1.3.0`, в ней эта ошибка исправлена.

---

Так же стоит добавить эти атрибуты в файл [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#name)

Обсуждение подобной проблемы на [Github](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/700)